# Comparision of the Ionisation Energy Change of the alkali metals and noble gases?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, atoms, periodic-trends

Currently I compare the ionisation energys of the alkali metals:

Li: $\pu{0.52 eV}$
Na: $\pu{0.50 eV}$
K: $\pu{0.42 eV}$

Where only a slight drop (appr. remain constant) occurs.

This ionisation energys occur **in comparision** at the noble gases:

Ne: $\pu{2.08 eV}$
Ar: $\pu{1.52 eV}$
Kr: $\pu{1.35 eV}$

Here we can observe a faster drop in the ionisation energy.

This diagram visualizes the numbers:

[image]

Source: https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/mw1_ge/kap_2/illustr/b2_1_1.html

How can we explain that? My first attempt was for the alkali metals: Due to the rising effective nuclear charge (values of Clementi: Li 1.2, Na 2.5, K: 3.5) the orbital energys of the "highest" s-Orbital raughly remain constant (despite of rising quantum number *n*) and so the ionisation energy does (Koopmanns-Rule).

But the same explanation can be taken for the noble gases ($Z_\mathrm{eff}$ for highest s orbital: Ne 5.7, Ar 7,7, Kr 11.3) Here we have even a faster rise of the effective nuclear charge … but an immense drop of the ionisation energy!

So something is missing in my explanation. Does the energy of the s orbitals influenced by another important factor? Does somebody have a better explaination?

Data from Huheey: *"Inorganic chemistry"*

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66492/why-is-the-first-ionisation-energy-of-a-sodium-cation-bigger-than-that-of-a-neon

Comment: @Nilay Ghosh As far as I can see relates this linked question Not much with mine. My question deals with the enormous *change* of the IE of the noble gases (relative to the Change of the alkali metals).